# How to remove fragment from fragment itself

Tags: java, android

I have an `Activity` which has the possibility to open a gallery, in order to display it I've created a `Fragment` subclass in which I do all of the customization.

The problem i'm facing is that I can't remove the `Fragment` in order to close the gallery.. What I've tried is the following:

```
closeGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                getActivity().getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        });
```

But it doesn't remove the `Fragment` from the `Activity`. What is wrong with the code? Am I missing something in order to be able to remove the `Fragment`?

If it can help here's how I add the `Fragment` to the `Activity`:

```
frame = new FrameLayout(NewsDetailsActivity.this);
frame.setId(R.id.galleryFragment);
setContentView(frame, new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("gallery", newsDetails.gallery.toString());
Fragment newFragment = new GalleryFragment();
newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ft.add(frame.getId(), newFragment).commit();
```

Comment: You try to open system gallery or gallery - your own implementation?

Comment: @ssh it's my own implementation, it displays images downloaded from a webservice

Comment: Oh. I got it. try to add `addToBackStack(null)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed add to back stack.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(frame.getId(), newFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Comment: yeah it works! Thanks a lot :) gonna accept as soon as I can

Comment: @Signo no problem :)